# Incorrect birthday your answer does not match the security information on file

Tags: icloud

Was resetting the password, I put wrong birthday, I gave me error message saying incorrect birthday your answer does not match the security information on file. The only option is put right birthday and typed new password is Anthony2022!asd1, and I got the message saying your password has been changed from now on use your new password to sign in to your account, thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Computer support questions should be posted to [apple.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: According to you thw password has been changed. So what do you want more than that?